# Handling server errors with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

It would be great if you share some knowledge with me! Here is my problem - we have an Android app. and a server. For some of the calls the client needs to send a previously obtained token from the server which is legit for a limited amount of time. If it happens that the token is not valid any more, an error is returned from the sever, a new token needs to be obtained and we need to retry the request.

But how can I handle such behavior with Retrofit? Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about you try and make a request with a callback, if the callback is a failure and the error message is that the token needs to be obtained, then you do a request to get the new token for example:

```
        connectionInterface.getSomeStuff(object, new Callback<ObjectPOJO>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ObjectPOJO objectPOJO, Response response) {
                //success
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if (error.getLocalizedMessage().equals("Token expire error")
                    connectionInterface.getToken();
            }
```

Then in your retrofit getToken callback, if it is a success you will redo the getSomeStuff method and if it is a failure, you let the user know. For example:

```
        connectionInterface.getToken(token, new Callback<token>() {
            @Override
            public void success(token token, Response response) {
                //success and token has been added
                //add the token to your request somehow...
                connectionInterface.updateToken(token);
                connectionInterface.getSomeStuff();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                //error let user know
            }
```

Let me know if you have any other question. I think this will be the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response! That sounds reasonable if I have just a single function which needs to be re-executed. What if there are multiple functions like 'connectionInterface.getSomeStuff()'? In this case how can I know which exact function to re-execute within 'connectionInterface.getToken()'?

Comment: https://futurestud.io/blog/oauth-2-on-android-with-retrofit/ check out that link. You can use it and then just try to incorporate the gettoken into the connection handler.